# Download Speed is Very Slow

Tags: download

I have a 27 Mbps WiFi connection with unlimited usage, and an HP laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Firefox as the web browser.

Today, I tried to download the latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS.  While downloading, my browser is showing a speed of Kbps.  Why is that showing Kbps instead of Mbps?

Comment: Does it still happen? Does it happen with other files?

Comment: yes it happened 5 times until now, when downloading other files my download speed is 100kbps-3mbps

Comment: Please run a speed test at fast.com or speedtest.net and post results.

Comment: speed test is showing 28.87 mbps

Comment: I am having the same issue speed is under 1.5 KB/s. I am wondering, is it due to the love of Ubuntu every one is downloading 18.04 and due to traffic on their server speed is slow?

Answer (score 0):

Same case with me too- maybe the site have high number of download requests at present.

There are alternative download sources listed on the Ubuntu website:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads